# How do you use то ли дело what does it mean?

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление

i've seen this expression a few times online and don't really understand what it means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`То ли дело` means "it's quite a different matter; it's another thing altogether; what a difference". It is used in comparisons, what follows `то ли дело` is shown as really contrasting the thing that precedes that phrase. Usually what follows `то ли дело` is shown as being much better than what precedes it:

> [fact 1], то ли дело [fact 2]

means

> [fact 2] is better than [fact 1]

For example:

```
В городе скучно, то ли дело в деревне.
Staying in town is quite boring, staying in the country is quite a different matter.
(That is, staying in the country is much less boring than staying in town.)
```

A couple of examples from Russian famous writers:

```
Истина-то не всякому достаётся - поди, добивайся! - пожалуй, за неё и десятью копеечками
со строчки не отбояришься! То ли дело обман! Знай, пиши да обманывай.
(М. Салтыков-Щедрин, Обманщик-газетчик и легковерный читатель) — 
Not everyone is up to the job of writing truth. Anyhow, just go and try to find it.
It's more than likely that you wouldn't even get it for a kopeck a line. But lies -
that's a different matter. Just scribble away any nonsense you like.
```

Or

```
Светлову шёл тридцать шестой год, но сейчас ему можно было дать все сорок.
Лысый, располневший, с почти квадратной фигурой мужчина - кому он нужен!
Соня права. То ли дело Ветрин! (И. Забелин, Без свидетелей) —
Svetlov was getting on for thirty-six, but now you could have given him
all of forty. Bald, stout, with an almost square figure, who cared for him?
Sonya was right. Vetrin was another man altogether.
```

Comment: Excellent explanation and examples. Thank you!